# How to quickly find sound assets

Tags: interface

I can easily find and edit all image assets in the image editor, but I was wondering how can it be done with sound assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see all the sounds that are being used by the blend file by using the 'Outliner'.

Change the display mode of the 'Outliner' by changing the dropdown box from 'All Scenes' to either 'Sequence', 'Blend File' or 'Data Blocks'.

[image]

'Blend file' and 'Datablocks' each have a 'Sounds' section which lists *all* the sound files that are in use in the current blend file. The 'Sequence' view will *only* show audio files in use in the Video Sequence Editor and not in other sections of blender.

To further filter the results in 'Sequence' view for just audio and not video or images type the extension of the audio files, in this case '.mp3' into the search box.

[image]

Each of these views only *lists* audio files that have been loaded into blender and not a direct way to *edit* the audio file.

Comment: are in those files the files used by logic bricks?

Comment: @rraallvv I had forgotten that sounds could be used by logic bricks, I have updated my answer to include a way to view sounds used by them.